# The alternate iplanet web server jars (KFCJDK11.jar and KOCLJDK11.jar ) in websphere Application Server 6.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webserver, websphere-6.1, servlet-3.0

Please any one suggest some jar files, Which is the functionality iplanet web server jars (KFCJDK11.jar and KOCLJDK11.jar ) does in websphere Application Server 6.1 jars does.

```
we are  using  from iplanet jar
    1. AppLogic
    2. TempletDataBasic
    3. TempletMapBasic
    4. ITemplateData
    5. IDataConn
    6. IQuery
    7. IResultSet
    8. IValList
    9. IAppLogic
    10. ISession2
```

I'm doing migration work , from "Oracle Iplanet Web Server" to "IBM Websphere Application Server".

I'm facing difficulty in migrating the code, please help me any to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those classes look like non-standard ones, thus probably have no equivalents at all in WebSphere. That's a risk you take when you code a Java EE application to a specific server's API.

You'll have to understand exactly what each class does and find a Java EE-generic or WebSphere-specific way to duplicate those capabilities. I don't expect anyone here on StackOverflow to be able to provide you that list.